# Equivalence Between Left And Right Cosets

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to get better understanding on left and right cosets.

Lagrange theorem holds for both left and right cosets, so for any group we will have the same number of cosets and the same number of elements in each left and right coset?

But not all groups are normal so not every left and right cosets are the same?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Try [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6396/27542)

Comment: If $C$ is a left coset, then $C^{-1}=\{c^{-1}:c\in C\}$ is a right coset.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown for any group right?